# How to add fixed images at the bottom of my page, having 2 of those fixed at the corners, and one of them stretch between them?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to add a group of images at the bottom of my page. I have 3 images: Left corner, middle and right corner.

Each of the images at the corners should remain "cornered" regardless of resolution or any other page width variation, while the "middle" one should stretch between the other 2.

I made a video to explain but I can't add any more links to this post :(

My programation skills are quite null, so I'll thank explanations and all that.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I guess I'm understanding a lil' bit. But i'm not sure if I should make a div, or container, or what. This seems to be working properly... Here's the bit of the code that I think should be the starting point:

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px">
  <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/2rhmufn.jpg" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:250px; z-index:5"/> 
  <img src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/k3ras4.jpg" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:250px; width:100%; height:48px; z-index:3"/>
  <img src="http://oi57.tinypic.com/2ry63pz.jpg" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; right:0px; z-index:4"/>
</div>
```

I want it to begin at the end of the sidebar (200 pixels from the left, if I can't just set it to start right there), and to occupy the whole bottom regardless of resolution. The central image (the blank bar) should repeat, or stretch the whole size of the container.

Thanks again.

Comment: could you share your html and css code?

Comment: I'm trying, but I can't make it. It's way too long, and it won't let me create a box to restrain it.

Comment: could you provide a working demo on fiddle? and please add your code in your question - http://jsfiddle.net/p6zoa4f1/ and check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I just added the code. I hope it works. [Here's the video that explains it:](http://youtu.be/vtRsir3DxPA) It was added over the video, so it's basically how it should work. Thanks.

Comment: that is how your code look like on fiddle to me - http://jsfiddle.net/p6zoa4f1/1/show/, so please update this one - http://jsfiddle.net/p6zoa4f1/1/ with your images or [image placeholder](http://placehold.it/) and you should only post relevant code.

Comment: read about css position, float and margin... these would get your problem solved.

Comment: As I said, my coding skills are completely null. I couldn't get my page to work on fiddle. I was thinking about adding 3 of    <img src=’IMAGE URL’ height=100 style=’position:fixed;bottom:0px;left:0px;z-index:999’/> one at left, one at right, and one to stretch. I'm not sure if it would work as I want.